# Get error "InvalidClientTokenId" in a container running in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-sts, sts

I have a container running in an ec2 instance attached with instance profile.

In my case, i have to use aws access key and secret key in the scripts running in the container to get access to aws resources in a different account in another aws partition.

I exported the env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and unset `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in the scripts.

```
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s" \
            $(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
    --secret-id arn:aws-cn:secretsmanager:********* \
    --query 'SecretString' --output=text | jq '.ACCESS_KEY_TEST,.SECRET_KEY_TEST'))

unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

aws sts get-caller-identity
#aws sts get-caller-identity --region <region> ##not working either
```

Whatever i try, i cannot get rid of the error `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It surely means that the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is bound to a AWS_SESSION_TOKEN and you need to provide it as part of your authentication.

The fact that you unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN means you are removing all presence of this part of the credential set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i am still not very clear. How to provide the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in my authentication?  Is not the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` bound to the credential of the iam role attached to ec2 instance? I want to unset the original credential set of the EC2 instance and use the new AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.